# Can a Python native extension build and return a dict without holding the GIL the whole time?

Tags: python, rust, cpython, gil, pyo3

Say I want to implement a native extension for deserializing a JSON object from a file.  For an object with many keys, the first part of the execution time will be I/O, and the second part will be filling the dict up.  I know it's safe to release the GIL during I/O, but it's generally considered mandatory to hold the GIL if you want to call builtin C API functions like [PyDict_SetItem](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_SetItem).

But shouldn't this not always be necessary?  The dict that I want to mutate was allocated within the extension's code and hasn't been returned yet; no other code holds a reference to it.  For deserializing large objects, the performance gain of not blocking other code while filling in many keys could be substantial, so I'm curious if there's a concrete reason this doesn't work.  Do the `PyObject*` C APIs mutate global variables under the hood?  If so, is there a way of finding out which ones are safe to call this way and which ones are not?

I'm surprised this isn't documented, as allocating and filling a large object purely within extension code before returning it to Python code is a common usage pattern.  I guess many of the well-known examples of this (numpy, pytorch) write their own types from scratch and so can define their own safety constraints for the C APIs of those types.  Whereas I'm trying to do it with built-in types like `dict` and `list`.

I tried the following Rust code to define a native extension that just builds a dict and returns it without holding the GIL:

```
use pyo3::{prelude::*, types::PyDict, ffi::{PyUnicode_FromString, PyDict_SetItem, PyEval_SaveThread, PyEval_RestoreThread}, AsPyPointer};

#[pyfunction]
fn generate_dict(py: Python<'_>, num: usize) -> PyResult<&PyDict> {
    let d = PyDict::new(py);
    let d_ptr = d.as_ptr();

    // unsoundly release GIL without Rust lifetimes affected
    let thread_state = unsafe { PyEval_SaveThread() };

    for i in 0..num {
        let rust_str = std::ffi::CString::new(format!("{}", i))?;

        println!("[{}] allocating pyunicode..", i);
        let py_str = unsafe { PyUnicode_FromString(rust_str.as_ptr()) };

        println!("[{}] setting item...", i);
        let result = unsafe { PyDict_SetItem(d_ptr, py_str, py_str) };
        assert_eq!(result, 0);
    }

    // reacquire GIL without Rust lifetimes affected
    unsafe { PyEval_RestoreThread(thread_state) };
    Ok(d)
}

#[pymodule]
fn unsounddict(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(generate_dict, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

If I run `generate_dict` using `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` with concurrency of 10, I get an output like:

```
[0] allocating pyunicode..
[0] setting item...
[1] allocating pyunicode..
[1] setting item...
[2] allocating pyunicode..
[2] setting item...
[3] allocating pyunicode..
[3] setting item...
<....abridged...>
[7] allocating pyunicode..
[7] setting item...
[8] allocating pyunicode..
[46] allocating pyunicode..
[46] setting item...
[0] allocating pyunicode..
[0] setting item...
[1] allocating pyunicode..
[1] setting item...
[2] allocating pyunicode..
[2] setting item...
[14] allocating pyunicode..
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The segfault happens around the time the 3rd thread starts running.

So this definitely is unsound and causes problems with CPython, but I'd like to understand why.  I've looked at [the source for `PyDict_SetItem`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61f2be08661949e2f6dfc94143436297e60d47de/Objects/dictobject.c#L1823) but there's no global variable usage or other suspiciously non-thread-safe stuff.  My only hunch is that it may be trying to intern the `PyUnicode` objects, but that's a difficult hypothesis to test.  I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable about CPython internals can shed some light on this.  Maybe it can be documented to open up future performance wins for extension writers.

Answer (score 1):

Python's allocators aren't thread safe. You're creating objects in parallel using said non-thread-safe allocators. Ergo, segfault.